# Анимирование меню игры в Юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Как создать класное меню? что то на подобий этого -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я создаю простые анимаций для UIPanel прячу и показываю слева на право или с низу на верх и обратно. Но хочу создать что то получше этого. Вы как реализуете анимаций для меню ?

Comment: 1) это всё легко делается ровно также, как и 2D игры - банально  через спрайты.........2 вариант - через картинки, которые через Animation сделать анимации (тут не обязательно спрайт) ........3) ассеты на assetstore, всякие tween, animation effects и пр.

Comment: Мы такое раскадровками обычными делали

Comment: Да я тоже сделал анимаций но дело в том что таймер как то странно работает скорей всего и за фреймов... и получается не синхронно